# Stock Levels Disappear after adding to Side Cart

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

Seem to have something in-correct. As soon as I add a product to the side cart all stock levels disappear from the front end. So your unable to tell if any ticket stock levels of other tours are available.

I have 4 tours, each with an Adult and Child Ticket available with 10 stock each. Limit stock is ticked in the channel's field.

**Here is what I have...**

```
 {exp:store:product 
  entry_id="{entry_id}"
 }

     <ul>
        <li><strong>Tickets available:</strong> <span class="store_product_stock"><!-- automatically set --></span>
        <li><strong>Price:</strong>
            {if on_sale}
                <del>{regular_price}</del><br />
                {price}
                <span class="label label-success">Save {you_save} ({you_save_percent}%)</span>
            {if:else}
                {regular_price}
            {/if}
        </li>
     </ul>

    {modifiers}

            <label class="control-label" for="{modifier_input_name}"><strong>{modifier_name}: </strong></label>
                {if modifier_type == 'var' OR modifier_type == 'var_single_sku'}
                        {modifier_options}
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="{modifier_input_name}" value="{option_id}" /> {option_name} {if price_mod_val} ({price_mod}) {/if}</label>
                        {/modifier_options}
                {if:else}
                    <input type="text" id="{modifier_input_name}" name="{modifier_input_name}" value="" />
                {/if}
                {if modifier_instructions}<p class="help-block">{modifier_instructions}</p>{/if}

    {/modifiers}

        <label for="item_qty"><strong>Quantity: </strong></label>
        <input type="text" id="item_qty" name="item_qty" class="input-mini" value="{min_order_qty}" />

       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Purchase Tickets" class="button expand" />

{/exp:store:product}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to this, Brad pointed me in the right direction...

The javascript method can only be used on a single product page. Try using  {total_stock} instead.

Worked perfectly.